# Convex functions and minimization

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis

Let $D \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be a convex closed set and let $f:\mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a convex function. Prove that if $x^{*}$ is a solution of

$$\min_{x \in D} f(x)$$

then there exists a $\beta > 0$ that makes $x^{*}$ a solution of

$$\min_{x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}} \left( f(x) + \beta \, \mbox{dist}(x,D) \right)$$

without restrictions (where $\mbox{dist}(x,D)$ is the distance between a point $x$ and the set $D$).

Comment: To be clear, is distance defined as something to theffect of $dist(x,D)=\inf\{ |x-y| : y \in D \}$?

Comment: Yes, I'm using this definition

Comment: This motivates the [penalty method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penalty_method).

Comment: Does $f$ have full domain, or have some other restriction on domain? If not, then $D = \{1\} \subseteq \Bbb{R}$ and $f : [-1, 1] \to \Bbb{R} : x \mapsto -\sqrt{1 - x^2}$, form a counterexample.

Comment: Sorry, it was not clear, but the domain of f must be $\mathbb{R}^{n}$

Comment: I think it comes from the fact that convex functions are locally lipschitz continuous.